# Creating a list from python output - add it to excel

Tags: python, excel, list, loops

I am running the following script:

```
    steps = data['features'][0]['properties']['segments'][0]['steps']
    
    values = data['features'][0]['properties']['extras']['waycategory']['values']
    
    print(values)
    
    print(steps)
```

to get this output:

```
[]
[{'distance': 0.0, 'duration': 0.0, 'type': 11, 'instruction': 'Head east', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [0, 0]}]
[[0, 33, 0], [33, 94, 3], [94, 99, 0], [99, 134, 3], [134, 151, 1], [151, 162, 3], [162, 176, 1], [176, 185, 0], [185, 220, 1], [220, 227, 3], [227, 230, 0]]
[{'distance': 51.9, 'duration': 12.5, 'type': 11, 'instruction': 'Head southwest', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [0, 2]}, {'distance': 275.6, 'duration': 39.6, 'type': 0, 'instruction': 'Turn left onto Hetzendorfer Straße', 'name': 'Hetzendorfer Straße', 'way_points': [2, 13]}, {'distance': 162.6, 'duration': 28.2, 'type': 4, 'instruction': 'Turn slight left onto Hetzendorfer Straße', 'name': 'Hetzendorfer Straße', 'way_points': [13, 20]}, {'distance': 367.6, 'duration': 41.0, 'type': 1, 'instruction': 'Turn right onto Altmannsdorfer Straße, B224', 'name': 'Altmannsdorfer Straße, B224', 'way_points': [20, 33]}, {'distance': 1152.0, 'duration': 112.3, 'type': 13, 'instruction': 'Keep right', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [33, 57]}, {'distance': 1011.6, 'duration': 81.3, 'type': 13, 'instruction': 'Keep right', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [57, 79]}, {'distance': 358.5, 'duration': 37.4, 'type': 13, 'instruction': 'Keep right', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [79, 94]}, {'distance': 153.5, 'duration': 18.1, 'type': 1, 'instruction': 'Turn right onto Sterngasse', 'name': 'Sterngasse', 'way_points': [94, 99]}, {'distance': 18.8, 'duration': 6.8, 'type': 12, 'instruction': 'Keep left', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [99, 101]}, {'distance': 2778.7, 'duration': 218.2, 'type': 4, 'instruction': 'Turn slight left', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [101, 126]}, {'distance': 814.4, 'duration': 91.2, 'type': 12, 'instruction': 'Keep left onto Süd Autobahn, A2', 'name': 'Süd Autobahn, A2', 'way_points': [126, 134]}, {'distance': 1857.7, 'duration': 167.8, 'type': 13, 'instruction': 'Keep right', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [134, 163]}, {'distance': 776.5, 'duration': 106.8, 'type': 13, 'instruction': 'Keep right', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [163, 184]}, {'distance': 11.1, 'duration': 4.0, 'type': 2, 'instruction': 'Turn sharp left onto B12a', 'name': 'B12a', 'way_points': [184, 185]}, {'distance': 351.4, 'duration': 55.2, 'type': 4, 'instruction': 'Turn slight left onto B12a', 'name': 'B12a', 'way_points': [185, 195]}, {'distance': 1171.3, 'duration': 113.3, 'type': 12, 'instruction': 'Keep left', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [195, 227]}, {'distance': 47.0, 'duration': 8.5, 'type': 13, 'instruction': 'Keep right', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [227, 228]}, {'distance': 12.2, 'duration': 8.8, 'type': 1, 'instruction': 'Turn right', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [228, 229]}, {'distance': 5.1, 'duration': 1.2, 'type': 0, 'instruction': 'Turn left', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [229, 230]}, {'distance': 0.0, 'duration': 0.0, 'type': 10, 'instruction': 'Arrive at your destination, on the left', 'name': '-', 'way_points': [230, 230]}]
```

from that output I want to create an excel file looking like that:

[excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Ww0.png)

What I've been doing so far was to add the following in two seperate scripts:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns =['distance', 'duration', 'type', 'instruction', 'name', 'way_points', 'exit_number'])


    steps = data['features'][0]['properties']['segments'][0]['steps']
    
    df = df.append(steps, ignore_index=True)
    

book = load_workbook('c:\data\Waypoints.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:\data\Waypoints.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')

writer.book = book

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='name', index=False)

writer.save()

writer.close()
```

and:

```
joinedlist = []

     values = data['features'][0]['properties']['extras']['waycategory']['values']

     joinedlist = joinedlist + values

df = pd.DataFrame(joinedlist)
    
book = load_workbook('c:\data\Waycategories.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:\data\Waycategories.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')

writer.book = book

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='name', index=False)

writer.save()

writer.close()
```

Which unfortunately creates two different tablesizes looking like that:

[two tables with different sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Ims.png)

Can anybody hint me the direction I am going wrong to receive the output I am looking for?

Thanks for your help - any hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
wc_list = []
duration_list = []
distance_list = []
wp_list = []

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:\data\ddwpwc.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
wb = writer.book
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns =['distance', 'duration', 'waypoints', 'waycategories'])

df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
wb.save('c:\data\ddwpwc.xlsx')

    waypoints = []
    distance = []
    duration = []
    
    steps = data['features'][0]['properties']['segments'][0]['steps']
    for dis in steps:
        distance.append(dis['distance'])
    distance_list.append(distance)
        
    for dur in steps:
        duration.append(dur['duration'])
    duration_list.append(duration)
           
    for wp in steps:
        waypoints.append(wp['way_points'])
    wp_list.append(waypoints)
        
    values = str(data['features'][0]['properties']['extras']['waycategory']['values'])
    wc_list.append(values)
    
Excelfile = pd.read_excel("c:\data\ddwpwc.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("c:\data\ddwpwc.xlsx", engine = 'openpyxl')
Excelfile["waycategories"] = wc_list
Excelfile["waypoints"] = wp_list
Excelfile["duration"] = duration_list
Excelfile["distance"] = distance_list
Excelfile.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='name', index=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```